# How do I move a set of changes from one git repro to another -- the repros aren't clones

Tags: git

Here's an interesting problem... I have two git repros on my machine.  They both were migrated from another source control system and the first one wasn't converted exactly like it should have been.  The second one works much better.

I have a bunch of changes in the first repro that I want to move to the other.  While the code is essentially the same between the two repros, they were created indepedently of each other and therefore have a different set of history.  (Code changes are the same, but the change numbers and other metadata is completely different)  How do I move my code to the new git repro?

Edit: I can't really just "copy" my files because the two repros are stuck in different points in time.  The "broken" repro with my code is forever stuck in the past.

Comment: Have you tried [git patch/apply](http://luhman.org/blog/2009/09/22/git-patch-tutorial)? Admittedly, it's not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a history graft to allow you to move the history from the 'old' repository to the new repository.

Let's say that you want to get changes from branch `foo` in repository X, and apply it to master in repository Y. First, let's get X added as a remote to Y so we can manipulate both histories:

```
git remote add tmp-X ~/repository-X
git fetch tmp-X
```

Now that both histories are in one repository, we can just cherry-pick to take the changes we want. Let's say the history looks like this in `master`:

```
commit 0d39ac6df9f5d6e7b50d670d705fa4aae049b70d
Author: Joe User <user@example.com>
Date:   Sat Oct 13 03:55:24 2012 -0400

    Common parent commit
```

And in `tmp-X/master`:

```
commit be79703c19475118b72655d1ea5d1957f3edea58
Author: Joe User <user@example.com>
Date:   Sat Oct 13 03:57:29 2012 -0400

    Another change I want to keep

commit 2a1e95c6cb458718448581664d9f8e6a0b260968
Author: Joe User <user@example.com>
Date:   Sat Oct 13 03:56:00 2012 -0400

    Change I want to keep

commit 0fdda21de3382acb005e9511e6ce95007f20e687
Author: Joe User <user@example.com>
Date:   Sat Oct 13 03:55:24 2012 -0400

    Common parent commit

    [some kind of junk in the commit message that changes the IDs]
```

We can `git checkout master`, then:

```
git cherry-pick 0fdda21..tmp-X
```

And now `master` looks like:

```
commit b2246afa547ee52028331d2aa59400bca1265581
Author: Joe User <user@example.com>
Date:   Sat Oct 13 03:57:29 2012 -0400

    Another change I want to keep

commit da36f4b6728aecfd3da7c63d9b1bd430c864858b
Author: Joe User <user@example.com>
Date:   Sat Oct 13 03:56:00 2012 -0400

    Change I want to keep

commit 0d39ac6df9f5d6e7b50d670d705fa4aae049b70d
Author: Joe User <user@example.com>
Date:   Sat Oct 13 03:55:24 2012 -0400

    Common parent commit
```

If you've had other changes in mainline, you might also find it helpful to branch off from a historical commit in `mainline` that corresponds to the base commit (`0fdda21` above), cherry-pick to this branch, then merge this temporary branch into mainline.

Comment: I would recommend using git rebase BASE_COMMIT --onto NEW_BASE_COMMIT instead of git cherry-pick "range". rebase will allow you to fix conflicts as they come, and you could use git rebase --interactive to do some additional cleanup (if needed)

Comment: Once I run the first two ommands to add the remote and fetch the changes, can I then purge all that crap from the good repro?  Otherwise I now have two repros filled with garbage.  (These are growing to over 20gb each)

Comment: @JesseWeigert, `git remote rm tmp-X; git gc --aggressive`

Comment: @JesseWeigert, note also that if the file content is largely identical between the two repositories, the fetch might not cause it to grow very much

Comment: Nah... my repros are so far diverged in terms of revisions(yet not code changes) that none of these commands are producing any sort of sensable output.  I'll stick with my broken repro for now.  Once I'm done with my current features, I can trash the whole thing as it goes into the "official" source control system.  Thanks everyone for your help.